# Create class with custom methods and methods from other class? Java

Tags: java, bukkit

I am working on a bukkit plugin and wanted to create a class 'User' that would be like Player, except has the extra methods I add. The issue is, I have to implement Player, and it appears that I have to add all methods from Player(it's an interface). I don't want to override their current values, though, I want to add to them.

Thanks.

Comment: If `Player` is an interface, it won't have any "values". It has no definitions nor instance variables, by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces by their nature have no actual methods to override. If you have to use the implements keyword, you have to write the included methods. That's how OOP in Java works.

If you find something that you can extend, however, you do not need to overwrite the methods inherited. And if you wanted to, you could make sure they run the parent function's code by including `super()` in your function call.

Comment: I know, I guess I forgot the mention that with the bukkit API you ovveride a method to hook into it. They at this point have values, but i don't know where I can extend from them, if I even can.

Answer (score 1):

The interface has no current values, as it's an interface.

I will say (from experience) that you do not want to create your own Player implementation as it won't conform with the actual implementation and basically be unusable.

It would be better to have a "management" class that references information to the player's UUID:

```
public class PlayerManager {

    private Map<UUID, PlayerInfo> info = new HashMap<>();

    //methods for getting/removing player info, etc. For example:

    public PlayerInfo getPlayerInfo(Player p) {
        return this.getPlayerInfo(p.getUniqueId());
    }

    public PlayerInfo getPlayerInfo(UUID uuid) {
        return this.info.get(uuid);
    }

}
```

And the info class:

```
public class PlayerInfo {

    private Object someInfo;

    public PlayerInfo() {...}

}
```

You can store the methods/information you need in the `PlayerInfo` class, and get it from a reference of `Player#getUniqueId()`

This is essentially the recommended way of handling this, and will not break between updates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you meant by " override their current values ".
If you implement an interface, you , by definition , declare that your class behaves like implemented class therefore you should override its methods.
Is making "Player" an abstract class an option ?

Comment: Bukkit has an interface API, and a concrete implementation. You build against the interface API and run against the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend CraftPlayer, however this will break with every Bukkit update and there are various other issues involved so I REALLY wouldn't recommend this option.

You could instead store the player object in a variable and then use lombok (http://projectlombok.org/) with the @Delegate annotation on the player object variable. This will create methods like below at compile time and will only require you to re-compile when new methods are added.

```
public String getName(){
    return player.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without implementing `Player`, just have a method for getting the player in your user class:

```
public class User{

  private Player player;

  public User(Player p){
    this.player = p
  }

  public Player getPlayer(){
    return this.player
  }

  //anything else you want to do

}
```

So, when you created the user, `User u = new User(player);`, you could easily access player methods too by just calling `getPlayer()` on the user. So for example, if you wanted to send a user the message `hello world`, you could do:

```
user.getPlayer().sendMessage("hello world");
```

and if you wanted to teleport the player to the location `location`, you could do:

```
user.getPlayer().teleport(location);
```

This is what I do for all my classes like this, and it works fine for me!

Comment: This is what I was considering, I was just hoping there was a way to user basically be a player and a user(I could do user.sendMessage() or user.myMethod()) But I cannot find where the player values are initialized or anything along the lines.

Comment: @Trevor you could always do something like change `.getPlayer()` to something short like `.p()`, so it's easy to type, or, you could add the methods you need into that class... So you could add something like `.sendMessage(String message)` which would do `this.player.sendMessage(message);`

Answer (score 0):

Player is implementation of CBukkit CraftPlayer, extend that instead. Instances of CraftPlayer must be managed from your own code instead of from CBukkit code, there is no skipping that step unless you want to get into ASM.